# Mount folder in order to simulate USB device

Tags: linux, usb

Is it possible to use a folder to simulate an USB device on Linux OS?

Using mount or creating a virtual /dev/sdx device

Thank you!

Comment: What does it mean "to simulate a USB device"?

Comment: An USB device is accessed through its mount point (a directory). What you want to do is not very clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately all the devices in Linux/Unix are files.

So to answer you about "emulating" an USB stick:

You can very well create an image file of a pen with dd, or an empty one if that, and format it; and then mount it via the loopback interface.

Supposing the formatted stick (with files) is /dev/sdb:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=imageusb.img bs=1024
sudo losetup --partscan --find --show disk.img
sudo mount /dev/loop0p1 /mnt
```

To umount and free it:

```
sudo umount /mnt
sudo losetup -d /dev/loop0
```

Comment: Yes, but this will behave like a normal mount point, not like an USB drive. "lsusb" will not show it, udev will not trigger any special action, and so on. Your answer is not complete.